# Why MOS transconductance is not zero even when drain current is constant?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, nmos, cadence

I am trying to plot transconductance \$ g_m \$ of the MOSFET below when \$ V_{gs} \$ varies from 0 to 1.8V.

The schematic is below. The drain current is fixed to a constant DC value 1uA by a current source.

From the definition of transconductance \$g_m = \frac{\partial I_{ds}}{\partial V_{gs}}\$  and with this case \$I_{ds} = 1 \mu A \$ and is a constant current so \$g_m \$ should be zero.
However, as seen from the plot gm is not zero at all.

I am running DC anaylysis and plot \$ g_m \$ from the result browser in Cadence Virtuoso.

Could anyone explain why \$ g_m \$ is not zero in this particular case?

[image]

[image]

PS. I added other curves:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The simulation you perform is not very meaningful.

The gate-source voltage usually determines the drain-current. In saturation the behavior is similar to that of a voltage controlled current source. However, you force a constant current through the transistor regardless of the applied gate-source voltage. I suggest that you have a a look at the resulting drain voltage. It would also be interesting to see how you calculate or obtain the value for the transconductance.

When done right, the simulation indeed will give a transconductance that is not zero. The transconductance is the linearized behavior for a certain operating point. It just tells you how much the drain current will change when the gate-source voltage changes.

Forcing a current through the transistor will change the operating point but it will not make the transconductance zero. In this particular case the operating point is set by a gate-source voltage and a fixed drain current which is problematic as the drain current is a function of the gate source voltage.

Update: The added plot shows the voltage at the drain of transistor. In the subthreshold region it almost reaches 40V (!), for a standard 180nm transistor this is way too high, the transistor can't withstand such a high voltage. Therefore the model is no longer valid.

Nevertheless the transconductance only gives you information about the transistor for a certain operating point, not about the actual circuit. To make things clearer think about a simpler case. A constant gate-source voltage of 1V is applied to the transistor. For sure the simulator will calculate a certain gm, which tells you how much the current would change in case the gate-source voltage changed even though this is not possible since the voltage is fixed. The same applies to a fixed drain current.

Comment: Thank you.
I have just added other signals.
I checked the drain current and it is 1uA.
For transconductance gm, I didn't calculate it by myself. It is from output parameters exported by the simulator. 
I tried to search for document how gm is calculated by the simulator but I couldn't find any info.
Could you explain more why gm can't be zero?
iD is constant so according to the definition, should it be zero?

Comment: @anhnha -- See my update

Comment: Thank you.
I have just added operating region of M0 and some markers for clarification.

Here is operating region notation:
0 = cut off,

1 = triode,
2 = saturation,
3 = subthreshold,
4 = breakdown,
And as you said, the MOS no longer functions correctly in break down region (region 4) from the picture.
However, as you can see from the picture, in region 3 (subthreshold) and region 1 (triode) transconductance gm is still non zero.
Could you explain?

Comment: @anhnha -- As I wrote in my answer. The transconductance is a property of the device and not of the circuit. When a 1k resistor is short circuited it still is a 1k resistor. When 1uA are forced through a transistor the transconductance doesn't vanish. When the transconductance is calculated nothing is known about the fixed current, because the transconductance is only a property of the device and its operating point.

Comment: Thanks but I am still confused about this. Transconductance is different from resistance case. Resistance is a physical quantity but transconductance is not. It is derived quantity. That is what make me confused.

Comment: It's almost the same. A resistance is voltage per current. A transconductance current per voltage. If you fix the current (or the voltage) the quantity stays the same. Assume that you change the vgs by 1mV the drain current has to change according to the gm of the transistor and it will. Since you force 1uA through the transistor the current will flow through another path like the rds of the transistor.

Comment: You've mostly got the right answer, except the end of the your third paragraph "but the forced current will have to find another path (e.g. through gds)." just doesn't fit with your small signal/bias answer - which is right.

Comment: @Mario +1 for the cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fundamental problem is that you've not quite understood what the equation actually means. I can see the flawed logic in why you wrongly say the differential is zero when Id is constant, but that is *not* how the mathematics work.

\$ \frac{\partial I_d}{\partial V_g}\$ is evaluated @ \$I_{ds}\$ of \$ 1 \mu A\$.

The differential is telling you the slope of the \$I_{ds}\$ curve. In other words if I wiggle one of the parameters a little bit the other one will also wiggle proportional to the slope and by the amount that I'm wiggling the first one. How much the curve changes and thus how much of a response to your wiggling depends upon *where* on the curve you are sitting.

To be rigorous this really should be written mathematically as:

\$ \frac{\partial I_d}{\partial V_g} \big|{I_{ds}=1\mu A}\$

The more obtuse way of saying this in EE speak is that you've mixed up the small signal and large signal aspects of the analysis.

From a comment you say `"I am still confused about this. Transconductance is different from resistance case. Resistance is a physical quantity but transconductance is not. It is derived quantity. "`

Well actually resistance is also a derived quantity here too, and is the slope of another set of curves. They are both very physical quantities and you need to look more into the details of why that is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have a question relating to this. Hope you can explain it.
For the circuit above,  if we superimpose a small sinusoidal signal Vsin on a fixed DC bias VGS, what is the small signal voltage gain?
According to the formula of common source Av = gm*ro.
However, due to fixed Id the small signal gain should be zero.
Could you explain the contradiction?

Comment: @anhnha you're doing it again ... you need to spend time looking at what bias vs. small signal means. Just because  Id is fixed doesn't mean there isn't a signal that is being amplified.  You need to work out what is going on for yourself, but as a hint ... what does a current source look like in terms of resistance?

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it now. I understand biasing and small signal analysis. The circuit above still has small signal gain because the output resistance ro is finite. I know that the circuit above will have gm and the value is determined by DC analysis. Current source acts as an open circuit in small signal model. It has infinite output resistance.